# IFIFO file in C

Tags: c, fork

The code:

```
            if (P2==0)
            {
               {
                    mknod("file1", S_IFIFO|0666, 0);
                    fd=open("file1", O_WRONLY);
                    write(fd,string2,strlen(string2));
                    close(fd);
                    execl("Ex2","Ex2",NULL);
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
```

P2 is fork call.

In the Ex2 file I have this code:

```
            fd=open("file1", O_RDONLY);
            read(fd, string3, 8);
            close(fd);
            printf("\n%d, %s", fd, string3);
```

I need to call Ex2 from P2 of Ex1 and Ex2 will print the string of the file1 FIFO file, but, when I run the first code, the program keeps waiting before to call Ex2, If I open another terminal and call file1 with cat, then, Ex1 continues, call Ex2 and show string3.

Any idea to avoid this waiting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a pipe for writing will block until there is a reader. You can change this behaviour by using the O_NONBLOCK option together with O_WRONLY, but this will only mean the open returns an error immediately when there is no reader.

You could probably open the file with O_RDWR to avoid the blocking, but i'm pretty sure the pipe's contents will be cleared when you close it.

But your example is not how pipes are normally used. A pipe isn't some kind of temporary storage to pass data to an exec'ed program; you use it for interprocess communication. For example, the parent process writes data, and the child process reads it. If you use a pipe this way, you have a reader and a writer at the same time, and there won't be any blocks as long as the writer keeps writing and the reader keeps reading.